# PNP / Remote provisionning : parameter in template for changing FieldDefault

Tags: default-value, parameter, pnp, remote-provisioning

in a template, I use "Parameters" element :

```
  <pnp:Preferences>
    <pnp:Parameters>
      <pnp:Parameter Key="test" >newvalue</pnp:Parameter>
    </pnp:Parameters>
  </pnp:Preferences>
```

the parameter is used to change a list name, and a field default value :

```
<pnp:ListInstance Title="My doc lib {parameter:test}".../>
<pnp:FieldDefault FieldName="myfield">{parameter:test}</pnp:FieldDefault>
```

When the template is applied :

- the list name is 'My doc lib newvalue' : ok
- the default valeur for 'myfield' is '{parameter:test}' : ko

Do I make a mistake in the template definition ? Or is there here a bug ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Currently PnP's token replacement feature doesn't work at `FieldDefault` level, that's why your token is not replaced.

As workaround you can implement your own replacement logic in the original xml file prior provisioning.
For example

```
<pnp:FieldDefault FieldName="myfield">##my_param##</pnp:FieldDefault>
```

......

```
templateXml.Replace("##my_param##", "my value");
```

This is just a basic sample, of course it's better to use regex for that purpose.